# SYS_REFCURSOR changes to REF CURSOR automatically and gives error in oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sys-refcursor

I have a procedure in a package with prototype:

```
PROCEDURE simpleSearch(p_keyword IN  VARCHAR2,
                       p_events  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);
```

and in package body my definition is:

```
PROCEDURE simplesearch(p_keyword IN  VARCHAR2,
                       p_events  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)    
IS
  BEGIN

    OPEN p_events FOR      
      SELECT *
        FROM event e, show s
       WHERE s.eventid = e.id;

  END simplesearch;
```

And when I run it I get in the debugging screen :

```
DECLARE
  p_keyword VARCHAR2(200);
  p_events  REF cursor;
BEGIN
  p_keyword := 'r';

  package1.SIMPLESEARCH(
     P_KEYWORD => p_keyword,
     P_EVENTS => p_events
  );

  -- DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('P_EVENTS = ' || P_EVENTS);

  :P_EVENTS := p_events; -- <-- Cursor

  --rollback; 
END;
```

And it gives error  `PLS-00201: identifier 'CURSOR' must be declared`

Why cursor type is changed to `REF CURSOR` even though I declared it as `SYS_REFCURSOR`?

Comment: Which database version are you working on?

Comment: "And when I run it I get" - no that's not true the procedure is not generating any code. The 3rd code block is also written by you so it's you who have changed `sys_refcursor` to `ref cursor`.

Comment: I did not change the code manually, is not that strange ? They must be same data type an I wrong? I have been working on oracle 11g XE.

Comment: @user272735 No, that code is generated by SQL Developer.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use REFCURSOR to store that output of the SYS_REFCURSOR. Change your calling block to below and it should work:

```
     DECLARE
       P_KEYWORD VARCHAR2(200);
       P_EVENTS SYS_REFCURSOR ;
     BEGIN
        P_KEYWORD := 'r';

         PACKAGE1.SIMPLESEARCH(
                       P_KEYWORD => P_KEYWORD,
                       P_EVENTS => P_EVENTS
              );
          /* Legacy output: 
             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('P_EVENTS = ' || P_EVENTS);
          */ 
           -- :P_EVENTS := P_EVENTS; --<-- Cursor
             --rollback; 
         END;
```

Comment: But this code is generated automatically from that I wrote in the package bodyi I am confused about why the data type of  p_events OUT SYS_REFCURSOR  changed to REF CURSOR even thoguh I did not do anything. And above this code I have another procedure which does do same thing in that code everything is ok. I just copy that procedure body, and changed definition in the body.

Comment: Ok not sure why the data tyoe changed. But most of the tools generate only a pseudo code and you need to fill in the logic and verify ther syntax.
In the procedure that is running fine, just check if you have 'REFCURSOR or 'REF CURSOR' you should not have space in the declaration

Answer (score 0):

It must be this

```
DECLARE
   P_KEYWORD VARCHAR2(200);
   P_EVENTS SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
```

or the long form (which you **had** to use I think it was before Oracle 10g):

```
DECLARE
   P_KEYWORD VARCHAR2(200);
   TYPE P_EVENTS_TYPE IS REF CURSOR;
   P_EVENTS P_EVENTS_TYPE;
BEGIN
```